# Is there any use of composite primary key?

Tags: sql

[image]

In `ENTITY _COMMENT` table why we choose composite primary key of `Entity_ID` and `COMMENT_NO` instead why we  can't take just `COMMENT_NO` as primary key.

Comment: I think there is no use of taking composite primary key , instead we can only take single primary key

Comment: comment_no is unique ,`autogenerated` `autoincreament` so it has no chance to be same

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's common practice in database design to use an artificial primary key like a "serial" column that is unique across all rows.

But the entity_id in your case is a good example of a column that has an **identifying relationship** with the entity. An identifying relationship is applied to a column that is part of the way you identify a row in a table. It's therefore part of the primary key for that table.

Comment: i am getting you, u are saying if we have a `user_info` table, we can't take `user_name `as primary key (because name can have same value).  so we take a `user_id` as primary key, but we can also take user_name as part of primary key because  in a way A name generally helps us to identify the row.

Comment: (user_id, user_name) would be an appropriate primary key only if user_id were not unique itself.

Answer (score 1):

In composite key, we are make sure the combination of those two keys will never repeat. In other words the combination will uniquely identify a particular row.

I think in your scenario there may be a chance of coming multiple entry of commentno against a single entity id.for avoiding that situation and ensuring the business integrity the combination is set as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Each entity will have its set of comments, identified by the `Comment_no` (1, 2, 3, etc.). So, different entities will have equal `Comment_no`, and this attribute cannot distinguish an `Entity comment` among all the others. Instead, the pair `(Entity_id, Comment_no)` *can* identify each single `Entity comment` among all the others and can be used as primary key.

Comment: In that case one user will  able to comment only  once on one  entity

Comment: @beginner , each time a new comment is added it will receive a new comment_no, even if it comes from the same user, so any user can comment any number of times.

Comment: then comment_no will always unique, for which set of comments u are talking that have same `comment_no`, please tell me.

Comment: The comment_no is unique *inside* the Entity. This allow to have an order for all the comments of the same Entity and to discriminate among them. But different Entities can have the *same* Comment_no, so this cannot be unique in the table Entity_Comment.

Comment: i understand now, but why we need to give them same comment_no , a serial column automatically give them unique `comment_no` for example : for `entity_id= 1` i may have comment_no. 1,2,3 and for entity_id=2 I may have comment_no. 4,5,6,

Comment: This is certainly true, but to define it in this way allows to use any algorithm whatsoever to give a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain me clearly. You have both Entity_ID and COMMENT_NO as primary key and since combination of both tends to be unique. Consider in ENTITY_COMMENT table you have already a value as **ENTITY = 10** and **COMMENT_NO = 20**. I ll give you some example,

```
If you try to insert a value as,

Entity_ID    COMMENT_NO
10           5          - Data will be inserted because COMMENT is not 20         
6            20         -  Data will be inserted because Entity_id is not 10           
10           20         -  Here data will not be inserted because the combination of Entity_ID and COMMENT_NO is same.
```

Hope your doubt is clear. If not let me know will clarify you.

Comment: if we will take `comment_no` as primary key how it can be same, for example if for every new comment which is added `comment_no` will be different, for example we can take `comment_no` as `int` `unsigned`,`autoincreament` value( like a serial column)

Comment: Yes you are right, for each new comment_no data will be inserted. But you should not have existing entity_id and comment_no together.

Comment: we can see in database design `comment_no` is not used before, so how i it can have existing value. and we are taking it as serial column, then how it can be existing or same

Comment: See you have composite primary key for **entity_id** and **comment_no**. So combination of them should not be same. But you can have same entity_id.